# workspace problem

Tags: 13.04

I have very strange problem in my Ubuntu system.

Say in my first workspace, I have three programs open. firefox, spreadsheet, and terminal.

now if I'm working on two tasks simultaneously, I would like all the stuff related to each task in two seperate workstation.

When I move to another workspace,(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>) and if I click on firefox icon, it goes immediately to the first workspace and opens the firefox which I opened there. next to the icons of each program opened in my first workspace, I see a light white arrow that says it is open(in 2nd WS) . I don't want it that way. I know I can go to second workspace and on firefox ico, I press open a new window. but I don't want it that way.

Earlier I have worked on CentOS. centOS  did not have this problem at all.

Both the workspace I would like to seperate, just like I'm using two computers at the same time. :)

Any suggestions/solutions?

Thanks,
Shilp

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "problem" at all. From my point of view this is totally logical and I wouldn't expect any other behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you click with the middle button of the mouse on the firefox icon, it should open a new window in the current workspace. If you want the GNOME experience instead of Unity, you could try [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/).